# what does this function do when calling itself from within?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

The following piece of code is a controller with crud operators for a model.
I cannot figure out what the Zone.find does when it calls itself in the function declaration and why it has to call itself.

```
var Zone = require('../models/Zone')

module.exports = { 

find: function(params, callback){
    Zone.find(params, function(err, zones){ 
        if(err){
            callback(err, null)
            return
        }

        callback(null, zones)

    })

},

findById: function(){

},

update: function(){

},

create: function(){

},

destroy: function(){

},
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but which part of it calls itself? `Zone.find()` is a different method from `module.exports.find()`.

Comment: What makes you think `Zone.find` is the same as the `find` returned by that module?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = { 

find: function(params, callback){
```

and

```
Zone.find(params, function(err, zones){
```

are two seperate functions.

by calling `Zone.find()` invoke the `find()` function which is exported in `Zone.js('../models/Zone')` and the return value of that function is exported as the `find()` function of the controller

Comment: Ah yes. The first is module.exports declaration and the Zone.find() is a mongoose.model method which is indeed exported. Now it makes sense. Thx